# Is there a collection that provides sorting, no duplicate elements, and the subList(index, index) method?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I need a collection that does not allow for duplicates, is sorted, and supports the `subList(startIndex, endIndex)` method. Does one exist, and if it does, what collection is it?

`TreeMap` has no duplicates, has sorting, but doesn't have `subList(index, index)`. `ArrayList` has `subList(index, index)`, but it can contain duplicated values. Are there any options?

Comment: `TreeMap` is not even a `Collection`. The closest you'll find is a `Set` or `SortedSet`, both of which are a `Collection`.

Comment: TreeMap does have two methods `subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)` which might do what you need, TreeSet does have corresponding `subSet()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for something called an **order-statistic tree**, which is a balanced binary search tree augmented with extra information so that, in O(log n) time, you can query the element at any index.  Because it's a binary search tree, it doesn't allow duplicates, and because you can query for the element at a given position, you can efficiently implement subranges; just hand back a new view of the tree where you keep track of the start and end index, so when iterating over the tree you can span that particular range.

The Java standard libraries do not provide an implementation of this data structure (I actually don't know of any language that does provide it).  I managed to find (on Google's cache) this implementation of order statistic trees, which contains two files:

- [An implementation of a red/black tree,](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3acLBUN4xBffgJ%3apeople.uncw.edu/adharg/courses/csc532/BookCD/clrs2e/RedBlackTree.java%20package%20com.mhhe.clrs%202e;%20redblacktree&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com) and
- [This code to augment it into an order-statistic tree](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aUNTgivUFErQJ%3anth.wpi.edu/classes/cs2102-D07/APril30-LastDay-Graphs/clr/OrderStatisticTree.java%20%22order%20statistic%20tree%22%20java&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that springs to mind is `SortedSet`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html

However, it doesn't let you do `sublist(int start, int end)`. You can do `subSet(E start, E end)` but it's unclear from your description whether that suits your needs. If you need the concept of actual indexing you probably want a `List` of some form. If no duplicates is important `Set` is a good starting point. Any `Collection` will allow you to sort based on a `Comparator<E>` so that criteria is less important -- just make sure to sort before access.

Answer (score 0):

With [indexed-tree-map](https://github.com/geniot/indexed-tree-map) you could do this:

```
SortedSet range = indexedTreeSet.subSet(
                          indexedTreeSet.exact(indexFrom),
                          indexedTreeSet.exact(indexTo));
```